# Laravel редирект после авторизации

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток, друзья.
Помогите разобраться, а то уже голову сломал... Задача - после авторизации на странице /login нужно сделать редирект на страницу пользователя с id в URL. Пример ниже.

Сейчас у меня прописано в LoginController.php такое:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/profile';
```

То есть редиректит на страницу /profile, однако нужно сделать вот так как-то:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/profile/{$id}';
```

То есть, чтобы в URL добавлялся id залогиненного пользователя.

В routers/web.php у меня прописано такое:

```
Route::get('profile/{id}', 'HomeController@index');
```

То есть при переходе на страницу /profile/user-id открывается страница с информацией о пользователе с указанным в URL id. Но в LoginController.php так не получается... когда прописываю `protected $redirectTo = '/profile/{$id}';`

то все работает, но только URL такого вида /profile/%7Bid%7D

Что не так делаю? Я так понимаю, что ID почему-то воспринимается как строка, а не цифра.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте просто посмотрим на класс `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`, этот класс использует особенность: `AuthenticatesUsers`,

Теперь давайте заглянем в эту особенность, она в свою очередь использует еще 2 особенности: `RedirectsUsers`, `ThrottlesLogins`

Из вашего вопроса, сразу понятно, что нам нужна первая, давайте посмотрим на нее:

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

trait RedirectsUsers
{
    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
            return $this->redirectTo();
        }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
    }
}
```

Единственный метод, который в ней реализован - redirectPath, который проверяет есть ли метод redirectTo(), если его нет, то будет попытка перейти по свойству redirectTo, если нет и его то идет в `/home`

остается создать метод в классе LoginController:

```
protected function redirectTo(){
   return url('/profile/',auth()->user()->id);
}
```

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#included-authenticating) написано, что если вам нужно использовать какую-то логику для редиректа, то свойство `protected $redirectTo` можно заменить на метод

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    // Получить $id
    return '/profile/' . $id;
}
```