# Как изменить редирект при авторизации в Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Использую встроенную авторизацию Laravel. Свойство protected $redirectTo = '/'; везде заменено и при входе/регистрации всё работает как надо. Но если залогиненым пользователем попытаться зайти в 'www.***/login' или '/register', редирект все равно происходит на '/home'.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622264/laravel-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/622368#622368

Answer (score 2):

Есть middleware, отвечающее за редирект залогиненого пользователя: `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home'); // вот тут можно настроить, куда направим пользователя
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

app\Http\Controllers\Auth -> LoginController -> protected $redirectTo = /home';
заменить на что тебе нужно protected $redirectTo = '/path';